# How to solve nonhomgenous recurrence relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm studying this topic in advance and I'm working on textbook problems. The problem is simple :

> Solve the following recurrence relation
>
> a) $a(n+1)-a(n)=2n+3$, $n$ is greater than or equal to $0$ and $a(0)=1$
>
> b) $a(n+1)-a(n)=3n^2-n$, $n$ is greater than or equal to $0$ and $a(0)=3$

The answer in the back of the text says:

> a) $a(n)=(n+1)^2$, $n$ greater than or equal to $0$
>
> b) $a(n)=3+n(n-1)^2$, $n$ greater than or equal to $0$

I'm new to this topic and I want to know a efficient way to solve this problem. It is also good if you explain only one of them but step by step explanation to answer would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recurrences of the form
$$ a_{n+1} = a_n + f(n) $$
are so common that they have a specialized notation, namely
$$ a_n = a_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k) $$

Note that this is not a *solution*, merely a different notation for the same problem -- if you write out the *formal* meaning of what the $\sum$ notation stands for, you get exactly the original recurrence back.

However, you probably already know some techniques for dealing with finite sum; for example the first one
$$ a_n = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2k + 3 $$
is just the sum of a finite arithmetic sequence, which equals the number of terms times the average of the first and last term (Gauss's trick), so we get
$$ a_n = 1 + n\frac{2\cdot 0 + 3 + 2(n-1) + 3}{2} = n^2 + 2n + 1$$
which you may be able to recognize as the square of $n+1$.

---

In the second recurrence you have $g(n)=\sum_k f(k)$ where $f$ is a second-degree polynomial. What I do with such things is to remember that $g$ in that case is always a polynomial *one degree higher*, and then I find its coefficients by expanding $g(n+1)=g(n)+f(n)$, simplifying, and then equating terms of the same degree in $n$.

Somewhere there's probably a nice canned formula that allows one to compute the coefficients of $g$ directly from those of $f$, but I don't care to go around remembering it -- it's not *that* often I have to sum polynomial progressions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general technique for linear recurrence relations. You start by solving the homogeneous equation

> $$ a(n+1)-a(n) = 0 $$

by assuming $a(n)=r^n$ and plugging back in the above equation which gives the characteristic equation

$$ r-1=0 \implies r=1 $$

which yields the solution $a_h(n)=c_1$.

The second step is to find a particular solution for the equation

> $$ a(n+1)-a(n) = 2n+3  \longrightarrow (2)$$

by assuming

$$ a_p(n)= An^2+Bn+C $$

and plugging back in $(2)$ to determine the constants $A,B,C$ to get

$$ a_p(n) = n^2+2n. $$

So the general solution is given by

> $$ a(n) = a_h(n) + a_p(n) = c_1 + n^2+2n. $$

To determine $c_1$ we exploit the initial condition $a(0)=1$ to get the final answer

> $$ a(n)=1+2n+n^2 = (n+1)^2. $$

Answer (score 0):

Given
$$
a(n+1)-a(n)=f(n)\tag{1}
$$
we can sum $(1)$ and get a telescoping series
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(k)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}[a(k+1)-a(k)]\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^na(k)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a(k)\\
&=a(n)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a(k)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a(k)-a_0\\[9pt]
&=a(n)-a(0)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
This sum is called a telescoping series because
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}[a(k+1)-a(k)]\\
&=[a_n\overbrace{-a_{n-1}]+[a_{n-1}}^{\text{cancel}}\overbrace{-a_{n-2}]+[a_{n-2}}^{\text{cancel}}\overbrace{-a_{n-3}]+\dots+[a_2}^{\text{cancel ... cancel}}\overbrace{-a_1]+[a_1}^{\text{cancel}}-a_0]\\[9pt]
&=a_n-a_0\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
That is, the paired adjacent terms cancel and the whole sum collapses, just like a telescope being put away.

Equation $(2)$ says
$$
a_n=a_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(k)\tag{4}
$$
Thus, if we know how to sum $f(k)$, then we can solve $(1)$.

There are many posts showing how to sum polynomials, so I will just quote a few:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}1&=n\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k&=\frac{n(n-1)}2\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^2&=\frac{(2n-1)(n-1)n}6\\
\end{align}\tag{5}
$$
Equations $(4)$ and $(5)$ should enable you to solve the problems you are given.