# Information about this type of recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, recurrence-relations

I've been noodling with a problem that requires me to find a set of recurrence relations and their solutions. In particular, all the recurrence relations are of the form:

$$
u_{n+1} = u_{n} + p(n)
$$
where $p(x)$ is a polynomial.

I was wondering the name of these sequences, what the solutions of $u_{n}$ are if you know $p(n)$ and the initial value, as well as any other properties these relations have.

Comment: Write the recurrence for $n=1, 2...n-1$, sum the $n-1$ equations, and you should be left with a formula for $u_n$ after simplifications.

Comment: Similar with interesting answers : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1174038

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a linear inhomogeneous difference equation. Maybe this is the name. If you know $p(x)$ and the initial value $u_0$, we get
$$u_n=u_0+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}p(i)$$
And you may observe, that $\displaystyle q(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}p(i)$ is a polynomial of degree $d+1$, if $p$ has degree $d$.

Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula is helpful.

Comment: Thanks - Faulhabers Formula looks like the next place to explore for my problem!